# Multiple HTTP POST over single socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to send multiple HTTP POST over single socket connection , but EPIPE broken once I read inputstream.

```
mBufferedWriter.write("POST " + "/base/mypath" + " HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n");
mBufferedWriter.write("Host: " + mIp + "\r\n");
mBufferedWriter.write("Content-Length: " + json.toString().length()"\r\n");
mBufferedWriter.write("Content-Type: application/json\r\n");
mBufferedWriter.write("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");
mBufferedWriter.write(json.toString() + "\r\n");
mBufferedWriter.flush();
```

My first POST will reach server. Am trying to achieve pipelining. Set keep-alive for socket also

Comment: Doesn't each connection require its own socket?

Comment: If I use separate socket my Post are honored. As I have to send hundreds of post need to reuse connection.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: But I have limitation in my server end

Comment: Does the server return with header `Connection: close`?

Answer (score 3):

[HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) involves more than just re-using an existing connection (HTTP Keep-Alive).  Pipelining involves having multiple HTTP requests in flight over a single connection at the same time, where a client sends an HTTP request but does not wait for its response before sending the next HTTP request on the same connection.  Both client and server have to implement support for pipelining in order to use it effectively.  Even then, there are issues related to pipelining `POST` requests, so they should nver be pipelined.  [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) is discussed in RFC 2616 Sections [8.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1.1) and [8.1.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1.2.2).

If you are not actually implementing Pipelining, only Keep-Alive, then you have to pay attention to the server's `Connection` response header, as it tells you whether you are allowed to send a new HTTP request over the same connection or not.  For an HTTP 1.1 response, if the server sends a `Connection: close` header, then the socket is going to be closed by the server after it sends the response, so you will have to create a new connection before sending the next HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache HTTP client (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html and set an Thread safe client connection manager.